# Visual Studio 2017 crash

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

We are running into a problem opening our MVC5 solution in Visual Studio 2017. It will show a message saying loading projects, followed by "Preparing solution" and then it just freezes. Some preliminary research has lead to suggestions like

1. Remove the hidden .vs folder
2. Repair installation by running as admin
3. Updating to the latest released VS build
4. Remove any node.js type folders that have deeply nested folder structure within the solution folder

However, none of these have worked. Has anyone else run into a similar problem using VS 2017 with their solution? There are no special commands on packages loaded on startup.

Comment: You could try uninstalling any third-party extensions (before opening the project). Particularly if you had been using these extensions with VS2015. Some extensions appear to need to be removed then re-installed for VS2017.

Comment: Thanks. We don't really have any third-party extensions except Resharper. I did remove it and tried with no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was able to finally get it to work. I updated to the latest Visual Studio build 15.0.0+26228.10, but that did not seem to help. After removing my .vs folder before opening the solution multiple times, it finally started to load. I have no 3rd party extensions or tools running.

Comment: same here, vs starts crashing out of nowere. Deleting .vs folder, open the project, close it(!) and then it works again.

Comment: please, let us know what is the path?

Comment: It should be in the same location as the solution file. This folder is typically hidden and can be seen by checking the View Hidden Items checkbox in the folder options. @aljohn-yamaro

Answer (score 1):

I installed visual studio enterprise 2017 version 15.0.0+26228.10. and productivity power tool extension. the studio keep crashing when load project. I uninstall everything and reinstall vs only, the crash problem disappeared.

Comment: I will try the new build. That is a different version than what I am seeing.

Comment: The new build did not work. I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Deleted the `vs` folder, but it didn't work.

Looked for recently changed files in the project, saw `Web.csproj.user` — when I removed this the project works again.

Answer (score 1):

Visual studio 2017 keeps crashing when i try to launch it,all i did was to launch visual studio installer go to more which is under the product am using then clicked on repair and that got me running again.

Answer (score 0):

We saw some lockups, especially during the start of Batch Builds, until we set this experimental feature to **False**:

**Tools** > **Options** : **Text Editor** > **C/C++** > **Experimental** : **Enable Faster Project Load**.

I don't know whether it could apply to your problem or not, but it is related to loading projects, so...

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and uninstalled the ankhsvn subversion plugin then closed and re opened vs 2017 ad it worked.

Comment: There is no mention by OP they installed the ankhsvn subversion plugin. Does this actually answer the question?

Comment: Your right there isn't no mention but that doesn't mean they haven't got it installed either. However might be worth disabling your plugins one by one to see if there's an issue with a particular plugin.